# How to implement synchronization

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

While using Room Persistent Library for sqlite, I realized that it does not have any "built in" construct for implementing synchronization (I want to prevent race conditions). So I decided to use a simple synchronized block to avoid race conditions. Is this a correct solution to achieve the goal?

MyRoomDatabase

```
public abstract class MyRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract RoomOperation operation();

@Override
protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration config) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
    return null;
}
}
```

RoomOperationWrapper

```
public class RoomOperationWrapper {
MyRoomDatabase myRoomdb;

public RoomOperationWrapper(Context mContext) {
    myRoomdb = Room.databaseBuilder(mContext, MyRoomDatabase.class, "datab").build();
}

public synchronized List<RoomEntity> getAllQuery() {
    return myRoomdb.operation().getAllItems();
}
}
```

RoomOperation

```
public interface RoomOperation {
@Query("Select * from datab")
public List<RoomEntity> getAllItems();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Are you accessing this object from multiple threads?

Comment: yes, this one : myRoomdb